# ¿Como puedo hacer que el while me funcione?

Tags: java, while

Directamente no me funciona, no imprime nada, no puedo encontrarle el error.
El enunciado del programa es el siguiente :

**Dado las notas y nombres de alumnos de un curso , imprimir los nombres de los alumnos cuya nota sea mayor a 7 .El ingreso finaliza cuando se ingresa una nota negativa**.

```
 String nombre;
 int nota = 0;

 Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);


 while(nota<0) {
     System.out.println("Ingrese nombre : ");
     nombre = teclado.next();
     System.out.println("Ingrese nota : ");
     nota=teclado.nextInt();
     if(nota>7) {
         nota = teclado.nextInt();

         System.out.println("Alumno con nota mayor a 7 : " +nombre );
     }

 }
```

Comment: Nunca te va a funcionar porque colocaste que nota es igual a 0 arriba y en la condición tienes que mientras nota sea menor a 0.

Comment: si ahora me di cuenta jaja gracias :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ver ... tenés varios conceptos mal. Primero, nunca te va a entrar al ciclo while porque fijate que la condición que le estás pasando es que la nota sea menor a cero, la cual nunca va a ser si arriba dijiste que la nota ES IGUAL a 0 !!!

Proba con este código y analizalo:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String nombre; 
  int nota = 0;

  Scanner teclado = new Scanner (System.in);

  while(nota >= 0) {
      System.out.println("Ingrese nombre : ");
      nombre = teclado.nextLine();
      System.out.println("Ingrese nota : ");
      nota = teclado.nextInt();

      if(nota > 7) {
          System.out.println("Alumno con nota mayor a 7 : " + nombre );
      }
      else{
          System.out.println("Alumno reprobado con nota menor a 7: " + nombre);
      }
  }   
}
```

Comment: Si , era ese el problema , muchas gracias @Nacho Zve De La Torre :)

Comment: Me alegro que te halla servido. Cualquier cosa preguntame de nuevo. Saludos hermano